# Questions about Pycocyanin

Tags: xenobiology, hard-science, photosynthesis, unusual-color

Okay, so I have been reading on phycocyanin for blue plants, for a spec bio project, and I have several questions. Which are all closely related in terms of how it functions.They are essentially all parts of the same question.

1: It says it is an accessory protein to chlorophyll, but does it *have* to be with chlorophyll for a plant to photosynthesize, or can it work independently?

2: Following from this, what is the chemical formula for its photosynthisis? Is it the same formula as chlorophyll? (**Edit:** To further clarify, as it seems I have caused confusion, I am asking how it *differs* from chlorophyll, I know the formula for Chlorophyll based Photosynthesis.) Does it still wind up producing oxygen and glucose like oxygen?

3: It says it is water soluble, thus it can't be present in the cell itself, does this mean that it can't supply energy to the cells? Or that is does so less efficently?

You can ignore this one, because this is less connected, but, if phycocyanin alone doesn't work out, is there any other options besides Chlorophyll + Phycocyanin, or do I just have to go with copying Cyanobacteria there?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on a Stack that deals with plant biology or chemistry; you're more likely to get accurate answers.

Comment: Then you can vote to migrate it, not sure how to do it myself. I will edit to make it clearer that it is worldbuilding.

Comment: (The bio and chem stacks are not "default" migration targets; you may have to delete the question here and ask it directly on a target stack.)

Comment: I'll give it some time, then move.

Comment: Asking for the "chemical formula for its photosynthisis" shows that you have *a lot* to learn. Start with the Wikipedia articles on [photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) and [photosystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosystem). Long story short, there are several different, complex and intricate chains of [light-dependent reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-dependent_reactions). And there are several different [photosynthetic pigments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_pigment). And no, not all photosynthetic processes are oxygenic.

Comment: P.S. To help understand what the auxiliary pigments do: the core photosynthetic photosystems work with red (photosystem II) and deep red (photosystem I) light. Only red and deep red light. The auxiliary pigments capture light with shorter wavelengths and fluoresce red light, thus converting part of the light energy with shorter wavelengths to the longer wavelengths needed by the core photosystems.

Comment: @AlexP Sorry, but it shows you have to reread my question, I was asking how it *differs* in phycocyanin, I know for chlorophyll it is 6O2 + 6H2O --> C6H12O6 + 6O2. That is common knowledge. You literally mentioned the thing that made me ask the question, "And no, not all photosynthetic processes are oxygenic", this is the exact reason why I asked how it differs in phycocyanin, because I know that they can differ in diffrent pigments. Some even produce hydrogen sulfide, iirc. I ask as I couldn't find anything about it for phycocyanin online.

Comment: @DanceroftheStars: That's the overall summary of the process. That reaction *does not happen*. It's just one simplified view of the overall effect of the process. (And it is incorrect, anyway. It is only useful for back-of-the-napkin calculations. The end product of photsynthesis *may* be glucose, but it may also be, and usually is, some other kind of carbohydrate.) (If you want a real-life example of photosynthesis which does not use any kind of chlorophyll, look at [proteorhodopsyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteorhodopsin).)

Comment: Okay, and about the second response, so phycocyanin cannot work on its own, thank you for answering one of my questions instead of dodging it. So I will likely have to use chlorophyll with it to get the colour I wish for. That is helpful.

Comment: There is some confusion here. The actual light-dependent reaction chains *do not* produce gluocose or any other carbohydrate. Their end results are the ordinary biological energy-carriers [NADPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide_phosphate) and [ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate). They are then used by other, light-independent, metabolic pathways to [sysnthesize the sugars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuBisCO). The photosynthetic pigments have nothing to do with carbohydrate synthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, and I am sorry for getting aggressive earlier, your first response just felt very condescending and insulting, so I got defensive.

Comment: Is this a worldbuilding question? Because this appears to be asking for help understand real world biochemistry, which would have been more appropriately asked on [chemistry.se] or [biology.se].

Answer (score 4):

1. In plants, accessory pigments are always associated with chlorophyll, but that isn't the case for all photosynthetic organisms.  Bacteria exhibit substantially more diversity in this area, and there are a number of bacteriochlorophylls that can similarly be used alongside accessory pigments, as well as completely different photosynthetic pathways that don't use chlorophyll at all.  Halobacteria, for example, use a single molecule called bacteriorhodopsin that performs photosynthesis by itself without any sort of chlorophyll analog, and, what's more, bacteriorhodopsin primarily absorbs *green* light, just like many accessory pigments, which at least provides a proof of concept that such accessory pigments can function on their own.
2. If by "formula for photosynthesis", you mean 6CO2 + 6H2O ⟶ C6H12O6 + 6O2, then that isn't really specific to the chlorophyll itself, but rather sort of encompasses the whole photosynthetic process.  Chlorophyll provides the energy to facilitate the hydrolysis of a water molecule, which provides protons needed to drive ATP production and reduce electron carriers, which engage with additional intermediates during the calvin cycle to produce sugar.  There are a whole bunch of hidden layers to that equation, any one of which can be different and still get the same end result.  Given that energy is really the point, and that energy need not always take the form of glucose, even the end result can vary and the system can still actually do the same thing.  Some have simpler photosynthetic pathways that work somewhat similarly to the plant pathway (though often with only one photosystem) and prefer carbon monoxide over carbon dioxide and so their summary equations look more like this: CO +H2O ⟶ CO2 +H2.  Some photosynthesizing bacteria don't use water and CO2 at all, and instead split H2S molecules to use as proton donors.  Their photosynthetic process can be summarized with the following equation:  18H2S + 6CO2 + 3O2 ⟶ C6H12O6 + 12H2O + 18S.  Others photosynthesize pretty much the same way plants do, but also consume organic material like heterotrophs do and so their biosynthesis pathways use totally different systems, mechanisms, and molecules than their energy production pathways.  The thing that has to happen is that an electron has to get excited, allowing a proton to be stripped off of something and then used to drive a pump.  There are a lot of different ways that could be done, and most of the similarity we see on earth has more to do with the contingency of common ancestry than their only being one way to liberate a proton from a donor molecule.  In a fictional setting, the possibilities are basically endless.  If you can justify how this process knocks off a proton that can spin an ATP Synthase molecule, it's a viable fictional photosynthetic pathway.
3. Phycobillins are water soluble (i.e. polar), meaning that they can't hang out inside the cell membrane because the cell membrane is non-polar.  They can kind of clump together and hang out on the outside of the membrane though, which is what they tend to do.  This would be a substantial issue in using it as a primary pigment, however, so if you are married to using Phycocayanin specifically, rather than just wanting a blue pigment, you will have to noodle around how to make it work without being able to be incorporated into the membrane.  Maybe this organism has photosystems that cluster around the membrane?  Maybe it has some kind of virus-like capsid encasing the membrane for some reason and that's where the photosystems live?  I don't know, but it not being able to exist as a membrane organelle does complicate things somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, it is much appreciated. I am not particularly attached to phycocayanin, as much as I found it just gives a teal-ish colour that I really like around the star in my system. But I am fine going with a different pigment if it can still give the same colour. And more on 3, how do they work with aqautic cyanobacterial then, because I read that phycobillins are most common in water-dwelling cyanobacteria, which wouldn't seem to work if they are water-soluble.

Comment: @DanceroftheStars: [Phycobilisome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phycobilisome).

Comment: I see, will have to look into those more.